# Spring Boot @Conditional annotation gets ignored

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am trying to enable scheduler based on certain properties (Condition) however it ignores my @Conditional annotation irrespective condition outcome. Any suggestions?

Conditional Class

```
public class SchedulerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return property#1 || property#2
    }

}
```

Configuration Class

```
 @Configuration
 public class Scheduler {

    @Conditional(SchedulerCondition.class)
    @Bean(name = TaskManagementConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    public void processJobs() {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's being ignored? What's the rest of your app doing? A minimal example with a test that reproduces the problem would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: It's getting into processJobs()  even condition is false

Comment: What is your scheduler condition and have you verified it works as expected?